# how to create multiple instances of UitableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create multiple instance of UITableView. I have tabbar in my view controller and on each tabbar item i have to load table view with data coming from web service. I have Tableview created using storyboard.

1. Each instance of table view will carry different data.
2. On click of uitabbaritem respective tabbleview instance should reload.

I don't want to use UITabBarController. All i want to do is to use single view controller and single tableview.

Also I am confused with my approach. Is is good to use single view controller as all i need is to update tableview ? In my opinion using UItabbarcontroller will be unnecessary.

Comment: @VladHatko Well, to be fair you could use the same table view and just load two sets of data into it.

Comment: @Rohit palod If you create multiple tableView, you should consider the memory is more than one , use one tableView you can load multiple dataSources when you switch the item. use multiple tableView is not commend, but you can set the isHidden to relize your requirement also.

Comment: TableViews are UI elements. You use `UITableViewDataSource` to provide the data and customization for the table. If the two screens are exactly alike outside of the data used by the tableView, you should look to use one table, and manipulate the data being used by it.

Comment: @ConnorNeville I agree with you but problem is , if i will use same table instance with different data sources then every time when i move from one tab to another i have to reload table with data source and which is time taking process that i don't want. My question is simple, is there a way to create multiple instance of table view ??. So that when i move from one tab to another all i have to do is showing table with respective instance.It will save time of reloading table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement. The best use case of Tab bar is to handle and maintain multiple instances at same time. Imagine a situation like you are working on meals application. For each tab you have to show different options loaded in tableview. Those all tabs maintain different states of tableviews. Where as maintaining things in a single view controller has to refresh and replace the old data to get new data into picture. Here it is every time required to load the tableview data. So, based on your requirement think about using tab bar or not. If you don't want to maintain different states of multiple tableviews at once, go for singleView Controller and Single Tableview.

Comment: Same I mentioned in reply to comment of @ConnorNeville. I know it is not good to use same table for multiple tab, everytime i have to reload table. That is why i asked for multiple instance do that moving from one tab to other do not need to reload table.

Answer (score -1):

You can maintain just a single instance of a `UITableView` and use the tab bar selection to decide which data source to use for it.  Here's a working example, with a view controller setup in storyboard to contain a tab bar and a single tableview.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarDelegate>

@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *model;

@end
```

Our model is three arrays, one for each tab in the tab bar.  These arrays are hard-code initialized here, but might just as well be initialized from a web service...

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *dataSource0 = @[ @"A", @"B", @"C" ];
    NSArray *dataSource1 = @[ @"1", @"2", @"3"];
    NSArray *dataSource2 = @[ @"doh", @"ray", @"me"];
    self.model = @[ dataSource0, dataSource1, dataSource2 ];

    self.tabBar.selectedItem = self.tabBar.items[0];
}

// the user pressed a tab, reload the table
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

// this is an important part: our data for the table is determined by 
// which tab is selected, return of the arrays, corresponding to the selection
- (NSArray *)currentDataSource {
    UITabBarItem *item = self.tabBar.selectedItem;
    NSInteger index = [self.tabBar.items indexOfObject:item];
    return self.model[index];
}

// these datasource methods always refer to the currentDataSource 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self currentDataSource].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *text = [self currentDataSource][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks, but it will not help me out. I really don't want to reload table every time when moving from one tab to other. It is time taking and user will never appreciate it .

Comment: Now I understand why you asked the question: you have misunderstood the meaning of reloading the table. It doesn't mean fetching the data again. It only means redrawing the visible cells. The user won't see it.  It takes about the same amount of time as one frame of video. Fetch the data when the vc appears (or before). Changing the table content and redrawing happens in one run loop cycle